# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received ''

Tags: node.js

What supposed to be the problem? all of the sudden when i npm run dev, my app did not work anymore.

error:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1000
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE('id', id,
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received ''
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1000:11)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Node\express graphQL\server.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: also i tried deleting node mules and package lock json, and then npm i again. Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to remove this line:

```
const test = require("");
```

Now, working fine