require() empty string id error on non-empty strings
When I try to run my js code there appears to be an error that shouldn't exist no matter what.
Basically i loop through an array of strings (paths), i try to import an object (using require) using each path in the array but it gives the error:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'id' must be a non-empty string. Received ''

I tried logging the array to the console right before the forof block got executed and all of the elements were non-empty strings. I also tried using a foreach loop on the array but it gave the same error.
const filePaths = [
  "./file1.js",
  "./file2.js",
  "./file3.js",
  "./file4.js"
];
// each file exports an object

filePaths.forEach((filePath) => {
  const fileObject = require(filePath);
  console.log(fileObject);
});

This code will result in that TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]
From what i could tell by the console logs, it seems that the error is thrown on the last element, no matter the length. In the example it's "./file4.js" which is still confusing because its not an empty string like the error says.
The error is somehow still thrown even if i check for an empty string before the require statement.
if(filePath === '') return;
const file = require(filePath);

And yes, i am sure the error is coming from inside that for loop

Are you e.g. bundling this for the browser?

You must have an extra comma that is not in the code you posted here, which will increase the array length and be interpreted by the forEach as an extra element passed to the require. Inside the loop just do console.log(filePath) as the first statement.

Hi, It may be that one of the modules has a statement like this const test = require("");  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963518/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-value-the-argument-id-must-be-a-non-empty-string
